# バッチファイルの文字列処理と挿入

Tags: batch-file

iperfというツールを使いスループットを確認していますが、
このツールの出力結果がExcelで処理しにくい出力形式のため困っております。

ツール起動時下記コマンドで実行していますが、せめて、日時を一番左に挿入
するようなバッチにしたいのですが、何か方法は御座いますでしょうか？

```
echo %date%%time% >> iperf.log

iperf3.exe -c 192.168.1.2 -t 20 >>iperf.log
```

```
Connecting to host 192.168.1.1, port 5201
[  4] local 192.168.1.1 port 62946 connected to 192.168.1.2 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec  5.00 MBytes  41.9 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   1.00-2.01   sec  3.25 MBytes  27.0 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   2.01-3.00   sec  15.4 MBytes   130 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   3.00-4.01   sec  13.4 MBytes   111 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   4.01-5.02   sec  4.00 MBytes  33.4 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   5.02-6.02   sec  5.75 MBytes  48.3 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   6.02-7.00   sec  8.88 MBytes  75.7 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec  9.62 MBytes  80.5 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   8.00-9.01   sec  20.1 MBytes   168 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   9.01-10.00  sec  11.8 MBytes  98.8 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]  10.00-11.01  sec  27.0 MBytes   226 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]  11.01-12.00  sec  26.2 MBytes   221 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]  12.00-13.00  sec  28.1 MBytes   236 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]  13.00-14.00  sec  29.1 MBytes   244 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]  14.00-15.00  sec  31.2 MBytes   262 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]  15.00-16.00  sec  30.1 MBytes   253 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]  16.00-17.00  sec  23.8 MBytes   199 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]  17.00-18.01  sec  33.0 MBytes   276 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]  18.01-19.00  sec  31.9 MBytes   268 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]  19.00-20.00  sec  28.1 MBytes   236 Mbits/sec                  
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-20.00  sec   386 MBytes   162 Mbits/sec                  sender
[  4]   0.00-20.00  sec   386 MBytes   162 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

Comment: 参考情報として、`iperf 3.9` には実行結果を JSON フォーマットで出力するオプション(`-J`)があります。

Comment: iperfの2系だとcsvで出力するオプションがあるようですね。3系ではjsonのみのようですが、csvに変換するpythonスクリプトがあるようです。[iperfの出力をCSV化する方法](https://qiita.com/yas-nyan/items/1405883e8aab24df11b2), [【負荷試験】iPerfの使い方とコマンド例,オプション ~帯域幅やパケットサイズ,ログ指定,ロス,遅い時の対処](https://milestone-of-se.nesuke.com/knowhow/test-tool/iperf3/), [片方向通信環境でiperf2を使うための下調べ (1)](http://mikioblog.dolphinsystem.jp/2019/09/iperf2-1.html), [Wiresharkでiperf2パケットの中身を解析して分かった驚愕の事実](http://mikioblog.dolphinsystem.jp/2019/10/iperf2udpwireshark.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

一度ワークファイルにログを出力し、そのワークファイルの行を日時付きでiperf.logに出力してはいかがでしょうか？

```
@echo off
set _DT=%date% %time%
iperf3.exe -c 192.168.1.2 -t 20 > work.log
for /f "delims=" %%x in ( work.log ) do (
    echo %_DT% %%x   >>iperf.log
)
```

Comment: 既に、iperfから出力されているログを、work.logと変換し、```for /f "delims=" %%x in ( work.log ) do (
    echo %_DT% %%x   >>iperf.log
)
```の部分を実行してみましたが、出力されたiperf.logの一番左に日時は挿入されていませんでした。

Comment: 「set _DT=%date% %time%」を実行していますでしょうか？

Comment: なるほど！そういうことでしたか。理解できました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell には `ConvertFrom-Json` というコマンドレットがありますので、それを使ってみてはどうでしょうか。

###### JSON形式でファイルに出力

```
iperf3.exe -c 192.168.1.2 -t 20 -J > iperf.json
```

**iperf.json**

```js
{
             :

    "intervals":    [{
            "streams":  [{
                    "socket":   5,
                    "start":    0,
                    "end":  1.000136,
                    "seconds":  1.0001360177993774,
                    "bytes":    6138101760,
                    "bits_per_second":  49098135859.606842,
             :
```

**PowerShell script**

```
Get-Content ".\iperf.json" -Encoding UTF8 -Raw |
ConvertFrom-Json | % { 
  $ctime = [System.DateTimeOffset]::FromUnixTimeSeconds(
    $_.start.timestamp.timesecs).LocalDateTime.ToString(
      "G", [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CreateSpecificCulture("ja-JP"))
  $_.intervals.streams | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Output("Datetime,Interval(sec),Transfer(MBytes),Bandwidth(Mbits/sec)")
  }{
    Write-Output(
      "$ctime,{0:f2}-{1:f2},{2:f2},{3:f2}" -f
      $_.start, $_.end,
      ($_.bytes/[math]::Pow(10,6)),
      ($_.bits_per_second/[math]::Pow(10,6))
    )
  }
} | Out-File ".\iperf.csv" -Encoding UTF8
```

**iperf.csv**

| Datetime | Interval(sec) | Transfer(MBytes) | Bandwidth(Mbits/sec) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021/09/08 18:43:16 | 0.00-1.00 | 6138.10 | 49098.14 |
| 2021/09/08 18:43:16 | 1.00-2.00 | 6094.85 | 48757.37 |
| 2021/09/08 18:43:16 | 2.00-3.00 | 6143.34 | 49153.20 |
| 2021/09/08 18:43:16 | 3.00-4.00 | 6051.59 | 48410.96 |
| 2021/09/08 18:43:16 | 4.00-5.00 | 6121.06 | 48966.44 |

Comment: [`Export-Csv`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-5.1)も有効かもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

既に指摘されているように`iperf3`にはJSON出力を行う`-J`オプションが用意されています。
また、ExcelにはPower Queryと言って外部データを処理しテーブルとして取り込む機能が用意されています。これを使うことでJSONファイルを読み込むことができます。

Excelで [データ] - [データの取得] - [その他のデータソースから] - [空のクエリ] を実行するとPower Queryエディターが立ち上がります。
Power Queryエディターで [ホーム] - [詳細エディター] に次のコードを入力すると

```
let
    json = Json.Document(File.Contents("C:\Path\To\iperf.json")),
    epoch = DateTimeZone.ToLocal(#datetimezone(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)),
    startTime = epoch + #duration(0, 0, 0, json[start][timestamp][timesecs]),
    list = List.TransformMany(json[intervals], each [streams], (x, y) => [date = startTime] & y),
    table = Table.FromRecords(list)
in
    table
```

Power Queryエディターにテーブルが読み込まれます。ここで [ホーム] - [閉じて読み込む] でExcelにテーブルが読み込まれます。